# Display Custom Post Type in Recent Posts

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, recent-posts

I have the following problem:

I have created a custom post type `matratze` and currently besides the custom posts no other posts exist. Hence, nothing is being displayed under the recent posts.

The custom post type looks like the following:

[custom post]

My recent posts do not get displayed:

[main homepage]

I tried the following:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'matratze' ) );

    return $query;
}
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: I can be totally wrong but is it not: `$query->is_archive()` ?

Comment: @charles, the link @Kare gave is for the `single-matratze`

Answer (score 3):

To display Custom Post Types in the regular Recent Post widget for sidebar(s),
 we use following function which works flawless for us.
*We use our own functions and try to prevent overhead often created by plugins.*

> Note: make a backup before adding this function into `functions.php`

```
/**
 * Display CPT on Recent Post widget
 *
 * @version WP 4.6.1
 */
add_filter( 'widget_posts_args', 'wpse241060_widget_recent_post_4_cpt' );
function wpse241060_widget_recent_post_4_cpt( $params )
{
    $params['post_type'] = array( 'post', 'cpt01', 'cpt02');
    return $params;
}
```

> Read more in [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widget_posts_args/)

Comment: Thanks ! For more details, see : https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/widget_posts_args

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress provides [`wp_get_recent_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_recent_posts/) function to retrive a number of recent posts from any post types. you can pass your custom post type as an arguments to retrieve recent posts lists.

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => '5',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'matratze',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
```

**Wordpress Core Recent Posts widget does not provide feature to list posts from custom post type. If you want to list post using Widget, you can use [Posts in Sidebar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-in-sidebar/) Plugin.** This plugins i very powerful and provides you many options to show posts based on many criteria including recent posts from custom post types.

**UPDATE:**

Here is code you can use for your specific case:

You are using Tab Widget to display recent posts which uses WP_Query. So you can use pre_get_posts to set post type filter.

```
function filter_recent_get_posts($query) {
    if (isset($_POST['tab']) && ($_POST['tab'] == 'recent')) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'matratze');
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_recent_get_posts' );
```

Comment: Would you be so kind to pack this into a hook or filter? I would appreciate your reply!

Comment: @Kare I have updated answers with hook action you can use.

Comment: Imho is there no reason to use a plugin for a simple thing like displaying CPT on Recent Post widget.